# XML De-Serialization and inserting a column with radio button for each row retrieved in search C#

Tags: c#, xml

Can we populate Fields lastName, fistNname and userName from the  below xml into a DataGrid View along with a column which has radio button. So that one user can select one row at a time and we can use value of field "userNname" to perform further transaction.

```
<ConfData>
  <CfgPerson>
    <DBID value="165"/>
    <tenantDBID value="101"/>
    <lastName value="GI"/>
    <firstName value="Sim"/>
    <employeeID value="simulator"/>
    <userName value="SimGI"/>
    <password value="[output suppressed]"/>
    <isAgent value="1"/>
    <isAdmin value="1"/>
    <state value="1"/>
    <isExternalAuth value="1"/>
    <changePasswordOnNextLogin value="0"/>
    <passwordHashAlgorithm value="0"/>
    <PasswordUpdatingDate value="0"/>
  </CfgPerson>
  <CfgPerson>
    <DBID value="257"/>
    <tenantDBID value="101"/>
    <lastName value="Scott"/>
    <firstName value="Mike"/>
    <employeeID value="00116019"/>
    <userName value="scottmp"/>
    <password value="[output suppressed]"/>
    <appRanks>
      <CfgPersonRank>
        <appType value="70"/>
        <appRank value="3"/>
      </CfgPersonRank>
      <CfgPersonRank>
        <appType value="47"/>
        <appRank value="3"/>
      </CfgPersonRank>
      <CfgPersonRank>
        <appType value="49"/>
        <appRank value="3"/>
      </CfgPersonRank>
    </appRanks>
    <isAgent value="1"/>
    <isAdmin value="1"/>
    <state value="1"/>
    <externalID value="Michael.Scott"/>
    <isExternalAuth value="2"/>
    <changePasswordOnNextLogin value="1"/>
    <passwordHashAlgorithm value="0"/>
    <PasswordUpdatingDate value="0"/>
  </CfgPerson>
</ConfData>
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Yes you can. Now go google and come back when you have an actual problem rather than just asking someone to write your code.

Comment: Not easily with your xml.  You have three level deep table.  The columns name are the elements under CfgPerson.  But rank has two columns appType and appRank.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            string xml =
                "<ConfData>" +
                    "<CfgPerson>" +
                        "<DBID value=\"165\"/>" +
                        "<tenantDBID value=\"101\"/>" +
                        "<lastName value=\"GI\"/>" +
                        "<firstName value=\"Sim\"/>" +
                        "<employeeID value=\"simulator\"/>" +
                        "<userName value=\"SimGI\"/>" +
                        "<password value=\"[output suppressed]\"/>" +
                        "<isAgent value=\"1\"/>" +
                        "<isAdmin value=\"1\"/>" +
                        "<state value=\"1\"/>" +
                        "<isExternalAuth value=\"1\"/>" +
                        "<changePasswordOnNextLogin value=\"0\"/>" +
                        "<passwordHashAlgorithm value=\"0\"/>" +
                        "<PasswordUpdatingDate value=\"0\"/>" +
                    "</CfgPerson>" +
                    "<CfgPerson>" +
                        "<DBID value=\"257\"/>" +
                        "<tenantDBID value=\"101\"/>" +
                        "<lastName value=\"Scott\"/>" +
                        "<firstName value=\"Mike\"/>" +
                        "<employeeID value=\"00116019\"/>" +
                        "<userName value=\"scottmp\"/>" +
                        "<password value=\"[output suppressed]\"/>" +
                        "<appRanks>" +
                            "<CfgPersonRank>" +
                            "<appType value=\"70\"/>" +
                            "<appRank value=\"3\"/>" +
                            "</CfgPersonRank>" +
                            "<CfgPersonRank>" +
                            "<appType value=\"47\"/>" +
                            "<appRank value=\"3\"/>" +
                            "</CfgPersonRank>" +
                            "<CfgPersonRank>" +
                            "<appType value=\"49\"/>" +
                            "<appRank value=\"3\"/>" +
                            "</CfgPersonRank>" +
                        "</appRanks>" +
                        "<isAgent value=\"1\"/>" +
                        "<isAdmin value=\"1\"/>" +
                        "<state value=\"1\"/>" +
                        "<externalID value=\"Michael.Scott\"/>" +
                        "<isExternalAuth value=\"2\"/>" +
                        "<changePasswordOnNextLogin value=\"1\"/>" +
                        "<passwordHashAlgorithm value=\"0\"/>" +
                        "<PasswordUpdatingDate value=\"0\"/>" +
                    "</CfgPerson>" +
                "</ConfData>";

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            //build table
            foreach (XElement CfgPerson in doc.Descendants("CfgPerson"))
            {
                List<XElement> appRanks = CfgPerson.Descendants("appRanks").ToList();

                foreach (XElement column in CfgPerson.Elements())
                {
                    string tagName = column.Name.LocalName;
                    if (tagName != "appRanks")
                    {
                        if (!dt.Columns.Contains(tagName))
                        {
                            dt.Columns.Add(tagName, typeof(string));
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        foreach(XElement rank in appRanks.Descendants("CfgPersonRank").Elements())
                        {
                            string tagName2 = rank.Name.LocalName;
                            if (!dt.Columns.Contains(tagName2))
                            {
                                dt.Columns.Add(tagName2, typeof(string));                            }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            //add data
            DataRow row = null;
            foreach (XElement CfgPerson in doc.Descendants("CfgPerson"))
            {
                List<XElement> appRanks = CfgPerson.Descendants("appRanks").ToList();

                if (appRanks.Count == 0)
                {
                    row = dt.Rows.Add();
                    foreach (XElement column in CfgPerson.Elements())
                    {
                        row[column.Name.LocalName] = column.Attribute("value").Value;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    foreach (XElement appRank in appRanks.Descendants("CfgPersonRank"))
                    {
                        row = dt.Rows.Add();
                        foreach (XElement rank in appRank.Elements())
                        {
                            row[rank.Name.LocalName] = rank.Attribute("value").Value;
                        }
                        foreach (XElement column in CfgPerson.Elements())
                        {
                            if (column.Name.LocalName != "appRanks")
                            {
                                row[column.Name.LocalName] = column.Attribute("value").Value;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        }
    }
}
```